# Classification of invariant hyperplanes in vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to follow the proof of the following theorem in my linear algebra's book:

**Theorem:** Let $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ and $f:V\to V$ is a linear operator. Then all $(n-1)$ dimensional invariant under $f$ subspaces are of the form $\ker \xi$ for some eigenvector $\xi$ of the operator $f^*: V^*  \to V^{*}$.

**Proof:** Let $U$ be a $(n-1)$ dimensional subspace which is invariant under $f$. Then it is easy to show that $U=\ker \xi$ for some $\xi \neq 0$, $\xi\in V^*$ (if this is not obvious then I can show the details). Cojugation operator $f^*: V^*\to V^*$ is defined by $\xi \mapsto f^*_{\xi}$ and $f^*_{\xi}(v)=\xi(f(v))$ for all $v\in V$.

Let's consider linear functionals $\xi$ and $f^{*}_{\xi}$. The book says that the kernels of $\xi$ and $f^{*}_{\xi}$ are the same, i.e. $U=\ker f^{*}_{\xi}$. I can show that $U\subset \ker f^{*}_{\xi}$. Indeed, if $x\in U$ then $\xi(x)=0$ and let's consider $f^{*}_{\xi}(x)$ and be definition it is equal to $\xi(f(x))$ and since $U$ is invariant under $f$ it means that $f(x)\in U$ and since $U=\ker \xi$ then it immediately follows that $$f^{*}_{\xi}(x)=\xi(f(x))=0,$$ which implies that inclusion $U\subset \ker f^{*}_{\xi}$ holds.

The books claims that the reverse inclusion also holds but I cannot prove it. If this is true then it means that functionals $\xi$ and $f^{*}_{\xi}$ are proportional, i.e. there is $\lambda$ s.t. $f^{*}_{\xi}=\lambda \xi$ which means that $\xi$ is an eigenvector of conjugation operator $f^{*}$.

So the only problem here is to show that converse inclusion is also true.

Can anyone show this please?

Comment: Your "conjugation operator" is typically called an "adjoint operator".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, exactly! you are right! My book is on Russian language and I was not able to translate it properly :) But could you help me with my question, please?

Comment: Another strange thing about your post: typically, we would refer to the image of $\xi$ under $f^*$ as $f^*(\xi)$, or perhaps $\xi \circ f$, or perhaps $\xi f$. The notation $f_{\xi}^*$ is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot deduce that the reverse conclusion holds, but there is no need to do so.

Note that $U$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace.  So, if $U \subsetneq \ker f_{\xi}^*$, then we must have $V = \ker f_{\xi}^*$, which is to say that $f_{\xi}^* = 0$.  Equivalently, if $f_\xi^* \neq 0$, then we must have $U = \ker f_\xi^*$.

So if $f_{\xi}^* \neq 0$, we can indeed deduce that $f_{\xi}^*$ and $\xi$ have the same kernel, so that $f_{\xi}^* = \lambda \xi$ for some $\lambda \neq 0$.  On the other hand, if $f_{\xi}^* = 0$, then we have $f_{\xi}^* = 0 \cdot \xi$.  In either case, we find that $\xi$ is an eigenvector of $f^*$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I cannot get the second paragraph of it. What do you mean by "this outcome is possible for some choice of $f,\xi$."?

Comment: I got rid of the confusing sentence and addressed your second comment.  See my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! BTW, in the last paragraph probably you meant ".. for some $\lambda$", right?

Comment: @ZFR I would say that the phrase "for some $\lambda$" is not strictly necessary.  If it helps though, yes: that is what I meant.